# How to transfer data between devices using snmp (oid-mib)

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, oid

I have some problems with SNMP.

I want to share "different types" of data from 3 devices to the manager device using SNMP.

Do I need to create my own MIB and OID for this?

Is it possible to do this data transfer job in c code?

Comment: How large is the data you need to transfer?

Comment: not large data, I want to share int values returned from my own algorithms to other devices on the network

Comment: I suppose that you could do that by defining your own MIBs, as long as they don't conflict with any real MIBs. The NetSNMP sourceforge has a [page](https://net-snmp.sourceforge.io/wiki/index.php/Writing_your_own_MIBs) about this, though, as the page mentions, it's only about creating the file, not about how to back up those objects with real values. On its own, SNMP is actually pretty simple and flexible, but the tools are not always the easiest to use, which makes people feel it's really complicated. I don't exactly know how to do what you want, but rest assured, it ought to be possible

Comment: I understood, thanks @TallChuck